# Db2/Oracle-Cannot get rid off spaces

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Management has decided to migrate from db2 Luw v9. to Oracle 11g.

This is the DB2 query I created to dump to a delimited file a bunch of data (within a bash script).

```
EXPORT TO /tmp/dod.v3.del OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL COLDEL| DATESISO MESSAGES /tmp/dod.v3.msg SELECT DISTINCT A.CAMID, A.POSTTIME, A.MODDATE,A.RID,A.SOFTWAREVERSION,B.IPINFO,B.NUMBE ROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL,C.TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS,C. TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED,C.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE, C.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME,CONCAT(A.MODELNUMBER,(CONCAT('-',A.MANUFACTURERID))) FROM DMS.STBHEADER A JOIN DMS.STBSTATUS B ON A.DMS_ID=B.DMS_ID AND A.MODDATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY AND A.CAMID NOT IN (-11,125,117) LEFT JOIN DMS.BBVODSTATS C ON A.DMS_ID=C.DMS_ID FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR;
```

Data output looks nice and neat like this

```
2925917748|2003-12-05-17.26.58.000000|2013-11-03|36816426252|740||0|||||H25-500
3030176931|2004-11-07-11.48.52.000000|2013-11-03|25167455119|797||15|0|4|0|0|HR44-700
3026464853|2004-11-07-12.40.54.000000|2013-11-03|25166398575|797||17|0|3|0|0|HR44-500
```

This is the ORACLE query I created to do the same (within a bash script)

```
SET ARRAYSIZE 5000 FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF HEADING OFF LIN 999 MAXD 999 NEWP NONE;
SET RECSEP OFF TERM OFF TRIM ON TRIMSPOOL ON TRUNCATE OFF UND OFF VER OFF WRA OFF;
SET COLSEP |;
COLUMN CAMID FORMAT 9999999999999;
COLUMN RID FORMAT 9999999999999;
spool /tmp/dod.v3.del.ora;
SELECT DISTINCT
A.CAMID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A.POSTTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6'),' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A.MODDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A.RID), ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A.SOFTWAREVERSION), ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(B.IPINFO), ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(B.NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL) , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(C.TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS) , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(C.TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTE D) , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(C.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE) , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(C.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME) , ' ') ,' '),
LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(CONCAT(A.MODELNUMBER,(CONCAT('-',A.MANUFACTURERID))) ), ' ') ,' ')
FROM
DMS.STBHEADER A
JOIN
DMS.STBSTATUS B
ON A.DMS_ID=B.DMS_ID
AND
A.CAMID NOT IN (-11,125,117)
LEFT JOIN
DMS.BBVODSTATS C
ON A.DMS_ID=C.DMS_ID;
```

Data output is a mess of leading/trailing spaces all over the pplace (added R/LTRIMS have no effect):

```
1814861090|2013-08-27-08.05.17.000000 |2013-08-30|28883762982 |736 |null |0 |4 |4 |0 |0 |HR21-700
2072851526|2013-08-27-08.05.29.000000 |2013-08-30|33064562144 |736 |null |1 |42 |42 |0 |0 |HR24-500
```

This is the DDL for the DB2 tables

```
                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
CAMID                           SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No
RID                             SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No
SOFTWAREVERSION                 SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     25     0 Yes
MODELNUMBER                     SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     25     0 Yes
MANUFACTURERID                  SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     25     0 Yes
POSTTIME                        SYSIBM    TIMESTAMP                   10     6 Yes
MODDATE                         SYSIBM    DATE                         4     0 No
NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL     SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes
IPINFO                          SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    100     0 Yes
TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS          SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 Yes
TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED   SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 Yes
DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE               SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 Yes
DAILYDOWNLOADTIME               SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 Yes
```

This is the DDL for the Oracle tables

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CAMID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER
 RID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER
 SOFTWAREVERSION                                    VARCHAR2(25)
 MODELNUMBER                                        VARCHAR2(25)
 MANUFACTURERID                                     VARCHAR2(25)
 POSTTIME                                           TIMESTAMP(6)
 MODDATE                                   NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(0)
 NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL                        NUMBER
 IPINFO                                             VARCHAR2(100)
 TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS                             NUMBER
 TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED                      NUMBER
 DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE                                  NUMBER
 DAILYDOWNLOADTIME                                  NUMBER
```

What am I missing here? How can I fix my query in Oracle??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is still in columns and Oracle (or rather, SQL*Plus) doesn't remove whitespace within each row's values, so even if you `TRIM` a string column where the values are different lengths, all rows will display that column with the same width. It's also increasing the column widths to allow for the hidden headers, which is making things a bit worse. The derived header for your second column, for example - if it was shown - would be `LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A.POSTTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6'),''),'')`, so the column would display as 67 characters wide even if all the value were shorter than that. You can partially stop that by aliasing the columns with shorter names, but you'd still end up with spaces for your null values.

The only way I've found to really strip everything down like that is to manually concatenate the columns with the separator character, which produces a single column of output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.CAMID
  ||'|'|| TO_CHAR(A.POSTTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6')
  ||'|'|| TO_CHAR(A.MODDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ||'|'|| A.RID
  ||'|'|| A.SOFTWAREVERSION
  ||'|'|| B.IPINFO
  ||'|'|| B.NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL
  ||'|'|| C.TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS
  ||'|'|| C.TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED
  ||'|'|| C.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE
  ||'|'|| C.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME
  ||'|'|| A.MODELNUMBER ||'-'|| A.MANUFACTURERID
FROM
STBHEADER A
JOIN
STBSTATUS B
ON A.DMS_ID=B.DMS_ID
AND
A.CAMID NOT IN (-11,125,117)
LEFT JOIN
BBVODSTATS C
ON A.DMS_ID=C.DMS_ID;

3030176931|2004-11-07-11.48.52.000000|2013-11-03|25167455119|797||15|0|4|0|0|HR44-700
3026464853|2004-11-07-12.40.54.000000|2013-11-03|25166398575|797||17|0|4|0|0|HR44-500
2925917748|2003-12-05-17.26.58.000000|2013-11-03|36816426252|740||0|||||H25-500
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3807b/1).

This doesn't need to trim the values, but if you had needed to do that then it would have been simpler to use `TRIM` rather than separate `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` calls, and the default is to remove spaces - so instead of `LTRIM(RTRIM(value, ' '), ' ')` you could just do `TRIM(value)`. (But being explicit doesn't hurt). I've also left out the `TO_CHAR` calls for numeric values to simplify things, but again you may prefer to have them set explicitly - in which case look out for the `FM` format modifier.

Some of your `SET` commands, `MAXD`, `NEWP` and `TRUNCATE`, [are obsolete](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apc.htm), and some of the others aren't needed any more - `COLSEP` in particular, since there's only one column in the output now.

If you are really getting the word `null` in the output then you have `SET NULL null` somewhere, maybe in a login script; that also won't appear in this concatenated version, as it's applied to the output column (again, only one, and that can't be null) not to individual underlying table columns.

Comment: Alex, you "nailed it". After removing the TRIM() and most SET commands, I get the output to match. However, I do not have a SET NULL  in my code but this is an easy fix. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.